# Php prime factorization time and size issue

Tags: php, python, int, prime-factoring

There is a `python` implemention code for *prime factorization*. It tooks about `0.1` second for returning the answer. I implemented that for `php`. In large numbers it runs about 3 seconds (And sometimes it never return the answer)

**NOTE:** I even used [`BCMath`](http://php.net/manual/en/book.bc.php) functions in php for handling very large numbers.

**NOTE:** All other functions inside this function (mentioned below), are tested separately, but there is a problem in one of them (pollard_brent) that use php built in function `gmp_mod`. When I run this:

```
// python handles these big numbers fine, and returns 1 for this:
echo gmp_mod(10000000000000000000001 , 2);
```

Gives me this error:

```
Message: gmp_mod(): Unable to convert variable to GMP - wrong type
```

My factorization code:

```
public function primefactors($n, $sort = false) {
    $smallprimes = $this->primesbelow(10000);
    $factors = [];

    $limit = bcadd((bcpow($n, 0.5)) , 1);

    foreach ($smallprimes as $checker) {
        if ($checker > $limit) {
            break;
        }
        // while ($n%$checker == 0) {
        while ( bcmod($n, $checker) == 0 ) {
            array_push($factors, $checker);
            // $n = (int)($n/$checker);
            $n = bcdiv($n, $checker);
            // $limit = (int)(bcpow($n, 0.5)) + 1;
            // $limit = (bcpow($n, 0.5)) + 1;
            $limit = bcadd((bcpow($n, 0.5)) , 1);
            if ($checker > $limit) {
                break;
            }
        }
    }

    if ($n < 2) {
        return $factors;
    }

    while ($n > 1) {
        if ($this->isprime($n)) {
            array_push($factors, $n);
            // var_dump($factors);
            break;
        }
        $factor  = $this->pollard_brent($n);
        $factors = array_merge($factors, $this->primefactors($factor)); 
        $n = (int)($n/$factor);
    }
    if ($sort) {
        sort($factors);
    }

    return $factors;

}
```

Any idea?

Comment: Just a shot, but according to the manual for [gmp_mod](https://php.net/gmp_mod), both arguments are supposed to be GMP objects, not numbers...oops, I need to read it more. Says a string is fine. But I would still suggest maybe trying to use an instance and see if that works.

Comment: uhhhh you don't even have `gmp_mod` in your code

Comment: @JonathanKuhn But in smaller numbers works fine. What do you mean about * I would still suggest maybe trying to use an instance* ? Do you need the whole codes?

Comment: looks like you are passing an array to `pollard_brent`, which suggests you are passing an array to `gmp_mod`

Comment: No, I don't need to "whole codes". Most of the GMP functions return an instance of the GMP object, not a number. You can also instantiate a GMP object with gmp_init. I was suggesting to create an instance of the GMP class for your numbers and pass those into the mod function.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As pointed out in the comments, the manual shows that both arguments must be a GMP object or a numeric string.  This works:

```
echo gmp_mod("10000000000000000000001", "2");
```

Smaller numbers may work as PHP will convert the integer to a string within the function, however `10000000000000000000001` is longer than `PHP_INT_MAX` so it won't work.

```
echo 10000000000000000000001;
```

Yields:

```
1.0E+22
```

Comment: Just to add to this, the large number will actually convert into a float with exponent `1.0E22`, https://3v4l.org/W6kad, which is wrong for the gmp functions.

Comment: Thank you. But  there is a problem. That very large number is a variable that is integer, so when I use this: `gmp_mod( (string)$var , "2");` It gives me error : `Unable to convert variable to GMP - string is not an integer`